# No https for nginx Server Name

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, openssl

I have configured nginx 1.4.1 to use tls/ssl using a self-signed certificate. I can connect over https using the LAN IP address only. I can also connect to the `server_name`, but only over http and it only displays the 'Welcome to nginx!' page. Any ideas on how to get https with the `server_name`? (`nginx.conf` is just the default.)

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.conf

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    root /srv/web;

    ssl_certificate     /srv/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/server.key;

    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Edit: Would it matter that I'm on someone else's (free/public) subdomain? I know to get a certificate signed by a CA you would need proof of domain ownership, but it shouldn't matter to nginx in my use case, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding default_server to the server stanza you showed:

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    root /srv/web;
    ...
```

Don't forget to restart.

Comment: Same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` to the configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`?

nginx only reads configuration files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Sure do. To clarify, my configuration was set up without ssl initially which working on the `server_name`. So I'm thinking it's something with the ssl specific config directives...